# Visualising multiple points using QuickWKT plugin in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, well-known-text

Using the QuickWKT plugin in QGIS, a command of the form

POINT (30 10)

draws a point at the desired location. However, how can I achieve to draw multiple points in one go? I am looking for something like this

POINT (30 10, 31 10, 33 10)

to draw three points in one go.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you are looking for something like this :

```
MULTIPOINT (10 40, 40 30, 20 20, 30 10)
```

You can then run the Multiparts to Singleparts tool to explode your multipoint into several point geometries and work from there.